# Filter event lists by today AND current time

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

Can the exp:cal tag filter events by date AND time? Example: I want to show upcoming events for the week but I want to exclude those that have already passed today.

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="today" show_weeks="3" event_limit="6" pad_short_weeks="n"}
```

Should I be using exp:cal? This is Calendar 1.8.14 on EE 2.11.9 (I know it's old but that's what the client has).

I can use a conditional like `{if {event_start_date format="%U"} > {current_time format="%U"}}` but then my event_limit parameter gets limited even more. I need the same future total amount each time.

Comment: I can use a conditional like `{if {event_start_date format="%U"} > {current_time format="%U"}}` but then my event_limit parameter gets limited even more. I need the same future total amount each time.

Comment: Have you tried EE date formatting? I know the current version of Calendar is supposed to allow regular EE date formatting (meaning you can input a date and time in your `date_range_start` param): https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/templates/date_variable_formatting.html

Comment: Tried that @jrothafer, problem is there's nowhere where they show using a time filter, so I'm guessing at it.

Comment: Trying this: `date_range_start="{current_time format="%U"}" ` but that returns absolutely nothing. This: `date_range_start="today @ {current_time format="%G:%i"}"` but that includes past events from today. I need to just see future dates and hide today's already passed ones.

Comment: Ok I think I got it! Had to use `date_range_start="today @ {current_time format="%g:%i %A"}"` - it needed this format for some odd reason - using epoch time was not doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date_range_start="today @ {current_time format="%g:%i %A"}"` did the trick, it wasn't recognizing epoch time in the loop. Thanks @jrothafer for the suggestion to re-look at the date formatting variables.

Comment: Groovy, glad to help. Mark your answer as correct as soon as the stack lets you so others can find the answer to this if they need to!

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code to hide **Past events** and only shows the events for next **1 week**.

```
{exp:calendar:cal pad_short_weeks="n" date_range_start="today" date_range_end="+1 week"}
```

If some weeks/days are missing then you can also try with the **{current_time}** variable available in **EE** to hide the **Past events**.

```
{if '{event_start_date format="%U"}' > '{current_time format="%U"}'} 
    {!--Your event data--}
{/if}
```

Comment: But then my total results gets post-filtered and my limit are ignored, which leaves me a much smaller record set. I tried this, please read the comments (including mine). Thanks.

Comment: I assumed that you've tried by limit="3" in {exp:calendar:cal}. Can you explain post-filtered means?

Comment: The exp:cal tag is filtering based on parameters, so it will produce X number of results. If I then use a conditional statement within the EE loop, the results start with X results and get even further filtered (call that "N"), so could end up with X-N results on the page. I want to see X results, so I have to filter everything at the top (in the loop) and not inside the loop. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I suggested to use if statement only if you need and in the case of any missing events. Don't take it necessary for ee loop. First try with normal ee loop. After that if you will not get some event than only try ee conditional statements.